# Cambiar la conexión en tiempo de ejecución Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Mi proyecto cuenta con una conexión a SQL Server con Entity Framework 6, pero quiero lograr una conexión dinámica, que me permita administrar diferentes modelos y almacenar información en diferentes bases de datos con SQL y no SQL.

Ejemplo:

**BD 1:**
`User (Nombre, Apellido)`
`Profile (Ciudad, Pías, Email, Cel)`

**BD 2:**
`Cliente (NombresApellidos, Localización, Email, Cel)`

**Importante:** Las BDs se encuentran en diferentes Servidores y diferentes ips, pero todo el código esta bajo el mismo proyecto en C#.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: no podes trabajar sobre dbcontext distintos?